# How to embed unicode in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, unicode

I haven't been able to find an answer that works for me.

How can I write an em dash in a Linux terminal?

Tried `Ctrl` `Shift` `U` 2014 but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use the program "gucharmap". For some characters, the "compose" key will be a good idea. Good to have it.